# Issue using attribute variable in T-SQL XML value()

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

```sql
DECLARE @NodePath VARCHAR(20) = 'C',
        @NodeVariable VARCHAR(20) = '@name',
        @result XML;
SET @result = '
<A>
    <B>
        <C name="Name01"/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C name = "Name02"/>
    </B>
</A>
'
SELECT T.c.value('sql:variable("@NodeVariable")', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @result.nodes('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@NodePath")]') T(c)
```

I want to acquire the attributes of the XML, like:

```
|Name|
|Name01|
|Name02|
```

But the result is:

```
|Name|
|@name|
|@name|
```

How to solve that problem? Since I want to create a function that takes path and attribute name as arguments, `OPENXML` function is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit simpler might be this:

```
SELECT x.n.value('.', 'nvarchar(20)') as 'Name'
FROM @result.nodes('/A
                    /B
                    /*[local-name() =sql:variable("@NodePath")]
                    /@*[local-name()=sql:variable("@NodeVariable")]') x(n)
```

The idea in short:

- Dive down below `<B>` (or use the *deep search* with `//` if you can be sure, that there will be no `<C>` in any other place)
- Find any element with the given name
- pick the attribute with the given name (attributes are singleton per element per definition)
- use `value()` on the *current node* to return the content.

What might disturb this: Multiple occurences of `<C>` below `<B>`

### UPDATE Some additions to XPath and `local-name()`

Just try this:

```
declare @result xml =
N'<A>
    <B>
        <C name="Name01"/>
    </B>
    <TheSecondInA />
    <B>
        <C name = "Name02"/>
    </B>
    <OneMore someAttr="x" oneMoreAttr="y" theLastAttr="z" >SomeText</OneMore>
</A>';

SELECT @result.value('local-name((//TheSecondInA)[1])','varchar(100)')
      ,@result.value('local-name((/A/*[2])[1])','varchar(100)')
      ,@result.value('local-name(/A[1]/*[2])','varchar(100)')
      ,@result.value('local-name((//*[@someAttr]/@*[2])[1])','varchar(100)')
      ,@result.value('local-name((/A/OneMore/@*[3])[1])','varchar(100)')
      ,@result.value('local-name((/A/OneMore/@*[last()])[1])','varchar(100)')

      ,@result.value('local-name((/A/OneMore/text())[1])','varchar(100)')
      ,@result.value('local-name((/DoesNotExist)[1])','varchar(100)')
```

As you can see, the function `local-name()` must get a *singleton XPath*.

- The *deep search* dives to the first occurance of a named node
- The same is returned by the *second element* below `<A>`
- We do not need this `(SomeXpath)[1]` if the path itself guarantees to return a singleton.
- Here we dive to the first element where there is an attribute called `someAttr` and pick the second attribute by its position.
- Similiarly we can pick the third attribute on a given path
- To get the very last attribute (or element) we can use `last()`
- If the current node is a `text()` node, or if the element does not exist, we get an empty string back.

Hint: With similiar XPath expressions you can use `.value()` to retrieve local content, `.exist()` to test for existance (or the lack of it) and to modify a given location...

Answer (score 2):

In the `value()` function you need to use the `@*[local-name()=...]` syntax e.g.:

```sql
declare @NodePath nvarchar(20) = 'C';
declare @NodeVariable nvarchar(20) = 'name';
declare @result xml =
N'<A>
    <B>
        <C name="Name01"/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C name = "Name02"/>
    </B>
</A>'
select x.n.value('(@*[local-name()=sql:variable("@NodeVariable")])[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') as 'Name'
from @result.nodes('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@NodePath")]') x(n)
```

Which yields:

```
Name
------
Name01
Name02
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works please. I thought `local-name()` returned the element name? But you're using it to return the attribute name - and I really want to know how :) thanks. Also why is the "*" necessary in `@*[`.

Comment: The `local-name()` function operates on node sets. When using `@*[]` the context of node sets are attribute names as opposed to element names.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Do you have any reference for that? I've spent hours trying to make sense of it all.

Comment: I wish the W3C XPath document was more clear on it. I kind of discovered by accident one day when reading [XPathNavigator.LocalName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.localname) and saw it talking about XPathNodeTypes of Element, Attribute, Namespace and ProcessingInstruction, and thought... hey, what if?

Comment: OK, so in this case `@` says to return a set of attributes, `*` says to get all of them, then inside the `[]` is a predicate to filter them? Wow!

Comment: @DaleK, I've added some additions to `local-name()` to my answer, might be interesting to you...

Comment: @DaleK the `@*[]` is a full wildcard, as with elements, so will match all attributes of all namespaces. You can also do `@foo:*[]` to match only elements in the `foo` namespace prefix, or `@*:bar[]` to only match attributes named `bar` (regardless of their namespace prefix).